# R: Aggregating over several variables and observations (depending on values) and creating a new variable

Tags: r, variables, aggregation

The data set has the following structure

```
    Key         Date         Mat    Amount
     <int>     <date>       <chr>  <dbl>
1  1001056    2014-12-12    10025  0.10
2  1001056    2014-12-23    10025  0.20
3  1001056    2015-01-08    10025  0.10
4  1001056    2015-04-07    10025  0.20
5  1001056    2015-05-08    10025  0.20
6  1001076    2013-10-29    10026  3.00
7  1001140    2013-01-18    10026  0.72
8  1001140    2013-04-11    10026  2.40
9  1001140    2014-10-08    10026  0.24
10 1001237    2015-02-17    10025  2.40
11 1001237    2015-02-17    10026  3.40
```

Mat takes values in {10001,...,11000}, hence A:=|Mat|=1000.

I would like to accomplish the following goals:

1) (Intermediate step) For each Key-Date combination I would like to calculate for all materials, which are availabe at such a combination (which might vary from key to key), the differences in amount,
e.g. for combination "1001237    2015-02-17"  this would be for materials 10025 and 10026 2.40-3.40=-1 (but might be more combinations). (How to store those values effienently?)
This step might be skipped.

2) Finally, I would like to construct a new matrix of dimension A=1000 where each entry (i,j) (Material combination i and j) contains the average of the values calculated in the step before.
More formally, entry (i,j) is given by,

1/|all key-date combinationas containing Mat i and Mat j| \sum_{all key-date combinationas containing Mat i and Mat j} Amount_i - Amount_j

As the table is quite large efficiency of the computation is very important.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I can do it with list columns in `tidyverse`; the trick is to use `group_by` to get distinct combinations of `Key` and `Date`. Here's the code:

```
materials <- unique(x$Mat)
n <- length(materials)

x <- x %>% 
  group_by(Key, Date) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  # Create a n by n matrix for each combination of Key and Date
  mutate(matrices = lapply(data, 
                       function(y) {
                         out <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n, 
                                       dimnames = list(materials, materials))
                         # Only fill in when the pair of materials is present
                         # for the date of interest
                         mat_present <- as.character(unique(y$Mat))
                         for (i in mat_present) {
                           for (j in mat_present) {
                             # You may want to take an absolute value
                             out[i,j] <- y$Amount[y$Mat == i] - y$Amount[y$Mat == j]
                           }
                         }
                         out
                       }))
```

If you really want speed, you can implement the function in `lapply` with `Rcpp`. You can use `RcppParallel` to further speed it up. Now one of the columns of the data frame is a list of matrices. Then, for each element of the matrices, take an average while ignoring `NA`s:

```
x_arr <- array(unlist(x$matrices), dim = c(2,2,10))
results <- apply(x_arr, 2, rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I stacked the list of matrices into a 3D array and found row means slice by slice. For performance, you can also do it in `RcppArmadillo`, with `sum(x_arr, 2)`, but it's hard to deal with missing values when not all types of materials are represented in a combination of `Key` and `Date`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think the indexing by i and j might be adjusted (names vs the number of row/column). When running the code on the full data set, the following error message appeared:  Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: I suspect this is because the value to be assigned to `out[i,j]` has length greater than 1. When writing the code, I assumed that for each combination of key and date, each material only appears once. When that doesn't apply, you end up trying to assign a vector to a scaler, which causes the error.

Comment: BTW, for better efficiency, you can modify the for loop to `for (j < i)` since only half of the computation is needed. The half above the diagonal is simply the negative of the lower half if you don't take absolute value.